# Display filename using Directory.EnumerateFiles

Tags: c#, regex, linq, file

I'm doing a file reader that needs to output a new file with a certain format.
Right now I'm trying to get all the information that I need to build the output file but I'm missing 2 pieces of information: the date of the file and the name of the files. For both of these fields I plan to use the name of the file so for the date a will trim the name to only get the date since the date is in the name.

I needed to get from every file in a directory the value after "fct=" and count how many time this value add up and I was able to do that using Regex expression but I cannot extract the name of the file I'm in so I can know in what file the "fct=" value was taken.
I was able to that with `Directory.Getfilename` before but now I cannot manage to use it since I'm using EnumerateFiles.

Here's example of the inputs= files:

```
**2020-03-02_TRS.txt**
<dat>FCT=10019,XN=KEY,CN=ROHWEPJQSKAUMDUCFCT=777</dat></logurl>
<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RTU FCT=4515</dat>LBZ=test.sqi</logurl>
<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RT</dat>FCT=10019</logurl>
<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RT</dat>fct=717</logurl>

**2020-03-02_SKU.txt**
<dat>FCT=666,XN=KEY,CN=ROHWEPJQSKAUMDUCFCT=777</dat></logurl>
<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RTU FCT=123</dat>LBZ=test.sqi</logurl>

The output i'm looking for is:
2x 10019 TRS
1x 4515  TRS  
1x 717   TRS 
1x 666   SKU 
1x 123   SKU
```

The TRS and SKU is just a part of the name so if i can get a way to find the name of the file and after i will be able to parse it to only keep the TRS or SKU.

Here's my code:

```
    class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int counter = 0;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:/LogParser/LogParserV1/test.sql", true);
        char[] delimiters = { '<', ',', '&', ':', ' ', '\\', '\'' };

        {

            Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=FCT=)[0-9]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            var fctlist = Directory
                      .EnumerateFiles(@"C:/LogParser/LogParserV1", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
                      .SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file))
                      .SelectMany(line => regex
                      .Matches(line)
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(match => match.Value))
                      .GroupBy(number => number)
                      .Select(group => $"'{group.Count()}','{group.Key}','FCT',");

            foreach (string fctnumber in fctlist)
               Console.WriteLine(fctnumber);
            }
            counter++;

            // Suspend the screen.  
            System.Console.ReadLine();
            sw.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it `2020-03-02_EXE.txt` or `2020-03-02_SKU.txt`?

Comment: Its both there is 2 files.

Comment: I see `TRS` and `EXE` files, I don't see `SKU` file. Where is `SKU` coming from?

Comment: My mistake i correct it thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it seems that the regular expression also captures `ROHWEPJQSKAUMDUCFCT=777` values and according to the output sample it really shouldn't. Perhaps, you need to change it to something like  `(?<=[^a-z]FCT=)[0-9]*`.

To keep a part of a filename in the output you can select an anonymous class and store this part in one of its fields. Something like this might work:

```
var fctRegex = new Regex("(?<=[^a-z]FCT=)[0-9]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
//Extracting the last part of a filename with another regular expression
var filenameRegex = new Regex("^.*_([A-Z]+).txt$");
var fctlist = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(@"C:/LogParser/LogParserV1", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file)
        .SelectMany(line => fctRegex.Matches(line).Cast<Match>())
        //define an anonymous class with two fields
        .Select(match => new
            {
            //one to store a filename 
            Filename = filenameRegex.Match(Path.GetFileName(file)).Groups[1].Value,
            //second to store a value
            match.Value
            })
    )
    //group by both filename and value
    //if you don't need to group the same value across similar files,
    //consider grouping before selecting an anonymous class.
    .GroupBy(v => v)
    //I assumed that you need your results sorted
    //feel free to remove it if you don't
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .ThenByDescending(g => int.Parse(g.Key.Value)); 

foreach (var fct in fctlist)
    Console.WriteLine($"{fct.Count()}x {fct.Key.Value} {fct.Key.Filename}");
```

Later, you can add the date in a similar fashion:

```
.Select(match => new
     {
          Filedate = //some parsing here
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another solution :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ConsoleApplication159
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp\test\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string patternData = "<dat>(?'data1'[^<]+)</dat>(?'data2'[^<]+)?</logurl>";
            string patternAttribute = @"(?'key'\w+)=(?'value'\w+)";
            string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(FOLDER, "*.txt");
            foreach (string filename in filenames)
            {
                Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
                string line = "";
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Match matchData = Regex.Match(line, patternData);
                    if (matchData.Success)
                    {
                        string data = string.Join(",", new string [] {matchData.Groups["data1"].Value, matchData.Groups["data2"].Value}).ToUpper();

                        Dictionary<string,string> dictAttributes = Regex.Matches(data, patternAttribute)
                            .Cast<Match>().GroupBy(x => x.Groups["key"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
                        if (dictAttributes.ContainsKey("FCT"))
                        {
                            string value = dictAttributes["FCT"];
                            if (dict.ContainsKey(value))
                            {
                                dict[value]++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dict.Add(value, 1);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> key in dict)
                {
                    string file = filename.Substring(0,filename.LastIndexOf("\\"));
                    file = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}x {1}\t\t{2}", key.Value, key.Key, file);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
         }
    }
}
```